I'm trying to add the Trix editor with ActionText without Webpacker into my Rails app
I'm trying to add the Trix editor with ActionText into my Rails app, but I'm not using Webpacker. I've been following the official documentation, but it seems to assume the use of Webpacker. Can someone please guide me on how to integrate Trix and ActionText without Webpacker?
Here's what I've tried so far:

Added the trix and actiontext gems to my Gemfile and ran bundle install.
Ran rails action_text:install to generate the necessary migrations, but through the error message enter image description here
Migrated the database using rails db:migrate.
Added has_rich_text :content to my model.

application.js looks like.
import "trix";
import "@rails/actiontext";
View sideenter image description here.
However, I'm not sure how to include the Trix editor JavaScript and CSS files without Webpacker. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#installing-importmap-rails

You can ignore the warning that you get at 2nd step if "trix" and "@rails/actiontext" imported in your application.js file.
Then, you should import trix in you application.scss:
@import "trix";

Or you can directly import CSS files in your view:
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "actiontext", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>

If you prefer second way, be sure actiontext is also linked in app/assets/config/manifest.js
//= link actiontext.css

Now all that remains is to add rich_text_area as form input:
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :content, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.rich_text_area :content, class: 'form-control', rows: 3 %>
  </div>

You can take a look this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/43441

I solved my issue with the help of CDN for both (Trix and @rails/actiontext). I will check your answer later. Thank you.
